# length of argument list (3) and CL-generated number of arguments (9) do not agree

Tags: python, c, kernel, opencl, pyopencl

```
xx_np = np.random.rand(16500).astype(np.float32)
u_np = np.random.rand(16500).astype(np.float32)
vector_np = np.random.rand(16500).astype(np.float32)
temp_np = np.random.rand(16500).astype(np.float32)
ss_np = np.random.rand(16500).astype(np.float32)
ctx= cl.Context([device])  #context
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx) #commandqueue
mf = cl.mem_flags #memoryflags
xx_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=xx_np)
u_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=u_np)
vector_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=vector_np)
temp_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=temp_np)
ss_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=ss_np)

q00=q0
prg = cl.Program(ctx, """
__kernel void dota( __global float *xx, __global float *u, __global float *vector, __global float *temp,__global float *ss, __global float *res, float q00, float s,float i)
{
    int index = get_global_id(0);
    int qindex= get_global_id(0);
    res[index] = xx[index]*u[index-1];
    res[index] = res[index]*u[index-1];
    xx[index]= xx[index]-res[index];
    float a=   pow(pow(xx[index],2)+pow(xx[index+1],2),0.5);
    float b=   pow(pow(vector[index],2)+pow(vector[index+1],2),0.5);
    if(b==0)
    {   i=vector[qindex]+q00;
        b=pow(pow(i,2)+pow(i,2),0.5);
    }       
    s=100*(a/b);
    ss[index]=s;
    temp[index]=ss[index];
}
""").build()
res_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, temp_np.nbytes)
prg.dota(queue, temp_np.shape, None, temp_g, xx_g,res_g)
res_np = np.empty_like(temp_np)
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, res_np, res_g)
print res_np
```

i cant set the parameters right. as i am new to kernel codes. cant make it work on my own."length of argument list (3) and CL-generated number of arguments (9) do not agree". this is the error message i get when execue my code.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I never used OpenCL with Python I can tell you didn't supply enough arguments when calling dota...

`prg.dota(queue, temp_np.shape, None, temp_g, xx_g,res_g)`

1. temp_g
2. xx_g
3. res_g

While dota has so many parameters.

Comment: thankyou for your reply. i figured out the same issue. but now i have changed it to 
prg.dota(queue, temp_np.shape, None, temp_g, xx_g,vector_g,u_g,ss_g,q00,s,res_g)

Comment: and now i am getting this error
"pyopencl.LogicError: when processing argument #6 (1-based): clSetKernelArg failed: invalid arg size"